# How to launch app by Automator from mounted disk in MacOS?

Tags: macos, automator

I have a **.dmg** package that mounts a disk. I would like to create launch program by Automator to execute sh-script from this disk. Is there any way to do this?

Disk and script are highlighted:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In Automator needs the following:

> /Volumes/iRule/start-irule-client.sh

[image]